# I ran the program as instructed in the book but it didn't work, error : unknown procedure

Tags: prolog

```
start :- action(state(left,left,left,left),
state(right,right,right,right)).

action(Start,Goal):-
plan(Start,Goal,[Start],Path),
nl,write(’Solution:’),nl,
write_path(Path).
% write_path(Path), fail. % all solutions output

plan(Start,Goal,Visited,Path):-
go(Start,Next),
safe(Next),
\+ member(Next,Visited), % not(member(...))
plan(Next,Goal,[Next|Visited],Path).
plan(Goal,Goal,Path,Path).

go(state(X,X,Z,K),state(Y,Y,Z,K)):-across(X,Y). % farmer, wolf
go(state(X,W,X,K),state(Y,W,Y,K)):-across(X,Y). % farmer, goat
go(state(X,W,Z,X),state(Y,W,Z,Y)):-across(X,Y). % farmer, cabbage
go(state(X,W,Z,K),state(Y,W,Z,K)):-across(X,Y). % farmer
across(left,right).
across(right,left).

safe(state(B,W,Z,K)):- across(W,Z), across(Z,K).
safe(state(B,B,B,K)).
safe(state(B,W,B,B)).
```

**
To run the program, you need to write 2 commands, write(Path) and start.
I got it in the introduction to Artificial Intelligence - Wolfgang Ertel book, it's on pages 76-77
**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy8mh.png

Comment: The error message shows a problem at line 6, column 10. Use ' or " instead of backtick character ` in "write" on line 6.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error you provided on the .png it seems that you have programmed the write_path procedure. Maybe you could add it to the question.

You have an error on this line:

```
nl,write(’Solution:’),nl,
```

It should be

```
nl,write("Solution:"),nl,
```

See that I have changed the string symbol.

After correcting that typo, I have runned the program as you show in here and it gave me:

```
procedure `write_path(A)' does not exist
Reachable from:
      action(A,B)
      start
```

But as I said before, there is no such thing as write_path(Something). Maybe you missed that?